# Getting error during response : error=HTTP 599: Stream closed

Tags: python, mocking, tornado, python-unittest

I am facing the same issue "error=HTTP 599: Stream closed", Could some one please suggest.

I am creating a mock for a class for endpoint testing.

```
# def test_post_wrong_data_validate(self):
#     body = {"account":{"id" : ""},
#             "member":{"id":"test"},
#             "device": {"id":"d10"},
#             }
#     body_data = json.dumps(body)
#     @gen.coroutine
#     def raise_exception(*args, **kwargs):
#         raise exceptions.BadRequest('who cares')

#     self._family_sync.return_value._validate_request.side_effect = (raise_exception)

#     request = HTTPRequest(self.get_url('/test'), method='POST', body=body_data)
#     self.http_client.fetch(request, self.stop)
#     response = self.wait()
#     self.assertEqual(404, response.code)
```

Creating a patch for my api class in setup method.

```
# patcher = mock.patch("ClassName")
# self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
# self.class_name = patcher.start()
```

Comment: Any reason your code is commented out?

Comment: You said "the same issue" -- what is this same referring to?

Comment: @Klaus , Please ignore the comments.

Comment: @James, I found another post where they have suggested to return the app from the method get_app, I was referring to that.

Comment: How about you edit an uncomment your code?